# Change CSS style with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change a CSS style whenever a button is clicked.  To do this I have a Javascript function which defines a new class for CSS (as well as several other things).  Currently the JS function looks like this:

```
scope.dropChange = function(dropValue, dataType) {
    scope.checkChangeCol = {
        'width': '8px;',
        'height': '20px;',
        'border': 'solid #000;',
        'border-width': '0 3px 3px 0;',
        'padding-left':'0px;',
        'margin-left':'13px;',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(45deg);',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(45deg);',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(45deg);',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(45deg);',
        'margin':'auto;'
}
```

*i took out a lot on unnecessary code.  if you think the problem doesn't have to do with the class,  can can add in the rest of the function.

The html for the section that uses this is:

```
<table class=buttons-table>
    <tr style="line-height: 100px;">
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="dropChange('all')">All</button>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="dropChange('room')">Room</button>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="dropChange('floor')">Floor</button>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="dropChange('building')">Building</button>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div style="{{checkChangeCol}}" class="checkmark"></div>
        <td><div class="checkmark"></div>
        <td><div class="checkmark"></div>
        <td><div class="checkmark"></div>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>checkChangeCol = {{checkChangeCol}}
    </td>
</table>
```

From what i can tell,  I believe i formatted the class within the function wrong,  so it isn't being used even though the data is found.  However,  I am unsure of how to actually fix this.

Comment: Are you using a specific library? I don't think this syntax would work out of the box.

Comment: checkChangeCol seems like it should be a function.. did you possibly forget to invoke it?

Comment: You have a object function of `scope.dropChange(dropValue, dataType)` where the function of `dropChange()` belongs to the object `scope`  but in your html click you are trying to call page function of `dropChange(dropValue, dataType)` - try changing `dropChange(dropValue, dataType)` to `scope.dropChange(dropValue, dataType)` in your ng-click

Comment: I don't think so.  I know that the function runs when i press the button,  as the other functionality (which i removed for this post) works fine.

Comment: You could just define a CSS class and then programmatically add the class with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you do not use simple document.getElementById('yourid').setAttribute('style', 'color: red') ?

Comment: Hey,  Just thought i would let you know I tried your method and it worked. I setAttribute to a new class and now it is working!   

Thank's so much

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using any jquery or JavaScript. But you will need to restructure your HTML

```
<button class="btn">click me<span class="ouch"></span></button>
```

And then use the active psuedo class to  add the effect

```
.btn:active .ouch { color: red}
```

Further info https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use jQuery? http://jquery.com

```
$(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
      $('#attrib').css({
         color: 'red'
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: No jQuery specified in the question tags

Comment: Perhaps our friend does not know jQuery lib.

Comment: Seems it's not that case